# Cannot open file via "Open from Path" in JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter-lab

My JupyterLab always start open at disc C:. Now I want to get in disc E: using the "Open from path..." deal with the files in E:, but keeping the C: as the starting-disc. So I would like to ask how can I do it (open E: in the leftside bar)? Because when I enter the path "E:", I got the response "Could not find path E:", but when I enter path "C:", everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I just get around the problem by making a softlink to link the E to a directory in C.

One other way would be this:

You commit the container as a new image:

> docker commit container_id newimagename

And create a new container based on newimagename, and you'll see that the directory will be changed to set directory.